# Convert String to DateTime with Leading Zero C#

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, leading-zero

I have a datetime in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`:

```
string datetime = "05/16/2018"
```

Now, as per the requirement, I need to convert this `string` to `DateTime`. Whenever I do so It removes leading zero.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(datetime, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Here, It gives output as `5/16/2018` but I need it as `05/16/2018`. So, how do I achieve this result?

Comment: You are posting this question again, I'm repeating: `DateTime` object does not have format. Formatting occurs when you want to show your `DateTime` object, so you are converting it to string and can choose in which format to show. Refer to [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: @SeM I don't want to format it but can I get the same date `05/16/2018` while parsing in DateTime?

Comment: The DateTime value is the 16. May 2018. Period. When I would debug it I will see 16.05.2018 as value, because of the german formatting, but the value inside the DateTime is the 16. May 2018

Comment: @JeetenParmar your question is unclear to me, `DateTime` is just an objects which stores number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) to your particular date,  in the [GregorianCalendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar?view=netframework-4.7.2) calendar.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If not, please tell me what you are still confused about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand that a `DateTime` is just an object that represents a point in time. It does not store information about how it is formatted. The following are the same `DateTime`, just in different formats:

```
05/16/2018
5/16/2018
```

because they represent the *same point in time*.

It's like how `int` behaves. It will "remove your leading zeros" as well:

```
int a = 05;
Console.WriteLine(a); // just prints "5".
```

Because `05` and `5` are the same `int`, as far as `int` is concerned.

Whether leading zeroes are added in a `DateTime` depends on how you format it. They only appear when you convert your `DateTime` to a string. `05/16/2018` and `5/16/2018` are different `string`s.

If you want the leading zeroes, just specify a date format like `dd/MM/yyyy` whenever you want to output it:

```
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.toString("dd/MM/yyyy")); // prints leading zeroes!
```

Comment: Your perception is somewhat wrong! I have checked that with a Test Console Application that your converted DateTime can contain leading zero without converting it to string if your machine DateTime format contain leading zero.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Whenever you are printing something, `Console.WriteLine` will call `ToString` on that object, which is "converting to string".

Comment: This was not the point! Point was that whether it contain leading zero if a string is converted into c# datetime. Yes! it can contain if machine datetime format contains leading zero because by default c# datetime format is machine datetime format. so there is nothing related to the behavior of `int`.

Comment: @TanvirArjel - No!  `DateTime` **has no format** full stop!  What you refer to as "machine datetime format" is a _string representation_ of the `DateTime` for whatever the machine culture is.  The `DateTime`, however, has no format.  A `DateTime` has no concept of _leading zeroes_ because it _has no format_!

Answer (score 1):

First of all your string `DateTime` format(`MM/dd/yyyy`) is confusing! It will give misleading value for a string DataTime value like `"05/08/2018"`. So you have to use `ParseExact` instead of `Parse` as follows:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime,"MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> It gives output as 5/16/2018 but I need it as 05/16/2018. So, how do I achieve this result?

You can simply achieve this my changing you machine `DateTime` format to a leading zero `DataTime` format! bacause by default C# `DateTime` takes the format of the machine `Datatime` format.

**Well, I have also checked with a Test Console Application to confirm that your converted `DateTime` can contain leading zero without converting it to string if your machine `DateTime` format contains leading zero.**

Comment: How do you change your "machine" DateTime format?

Answer (score 0):

`"5/16/2018"` is string presentation od DateTime value.
If you want to output it with leading zero, you can use custom format:

```
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: There is no issue with String format. But I need it as `DateTime` only so I need to parse it.

Comment: @JeetenParmar so, I don't understand your question. What does it mean "t removes leading zero."? Who removes? When?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` removes leading zero and It returns result `5/16/2018` instead of `05/16/2018`

Comment: @JeetenParmar DateTime internal saves data just as `long` value. it does not have leadeng zeros - it's only string presentation of `long`. So you can output it with `0` or without, or anyway you want. But the value is the same everytime